# Convert x,y pixel positions of JPEG after georeferenced to GeoTIFF file x,y pixel positions

Tags: python, gdal

New to GDAL. I have a JPEG file that I have some data in x, y pixel positions. I georeference this image with gdal translate and some gcp(s). How to translate (transform) these x, y pixel positions from the source image to the respective x, y pixel positions on the result GeoTIFF image?

Comment: If you simply georeferenced the image, without any reprojection, every x/y pixel of the source matches the same exact x/y pixel of the target file

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`gdalwarp`](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalwarp.html) to do this. In addition to your GCP's you need the coordinate reference system CRS which should be defined corresponding to your GPC, define a resolution of the resulting image (`-tr xres yres`), a resampling algorithm (`-r bilinear` if needed) and and the output format `-of GTiff`.

### Example

```bsh
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:NUMBER -gcp IX1 IY1 WX1 WY1 -gcp IX2 IY2 WX2 WY2 -gcp IX3 IY3 WX3 WY3 ... src.jpg src_translate.jpg
gdalwarp -tr XRES YRES -r bilinear -of GTiff src_trans.jpg dst_.tif
```

The complete `gdalwarp` parameter set depends on the data input (source of the image location, coordinate system etc.) and the destination coordinate system.

Comment: I edited my question cause i don't think i made myself very clear,by pixel coords i mean pixel position values ,how can your answer make me traslate these x,y image positions from the source image to the tif image.